# Webpack Build at Runtime

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I am planning to build an vuejs app which is capable of modular build i.e. user will get option to select multiple fields and from the selected fields/options the app will make a custom build and provide the build to the user.

So here I need a clear idea/concept how to solve this issue with Webpack.

Comment: I dont understand your point -- you include in index.js whatever deps and they go to result bundle. And what means 'custom build and provide the build to the user' -- what user gonna do with this build?

Comment: So the app basically builds a JS file which imports other multiple jJS files. Now any user might want to get a custom build with specified imports. I am trying to achieve this. Any help?

Comment: This is unclear. As a user I want to use angular, lodash and your app - I put in package.json angular, lodash and (???)... I never want to manually download any of your builds and put it into my source code.

Comment: So let me give you an example, in Bootstrap project you can find that it imports multiple components (like btn, table, alert etc) to build one single file. So in that case if a user wants only btn component in that file. How he would get that. Here I want to build a system which will provide custom build which will have only those components he/she might use.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are searching for is to define multiple entry points in webpack.

[Here is some information regarding entry points](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/)

So, if you are able to tell the configuration file that what are the entry points, it'll create separate chunks for different entry points hereby constructing your custom builds.